# Webflux Webfilter Performance

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have an issue with overall application throughput while using WebFilter, without the Filter I was able to get 1,000 request per second easily but when enable WebFilter to log response and response time I see application can't handle similar load. It just because of the filter enabled no other change. I'm not clear why this filter creates the bottleneck.

Any suggestion or recommendation please?

```
@Component
public class CustomFilter implements WebFilter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomFilter.class);

    @Value("${log.enabled:true}")
    private boolean isLogEnabled = true;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        if (!isLogEnabled) {
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        } else {
            final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            LOGGER.info("Request: method={}, uri={}, headers={}", exchange.getRequest().getMethod(),
                    exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath(), exchange.getRequest().getHeaders());
            ServerWebExchangeDecorator exchangeDecorator = new ServerWebExchangeDecorator(exchange) {
                @Override
                public ServerHttpRequest getRequest() {
                    return new RequestLoggingInterceptor(super.getRequest());
                }

                @Override
                public ServerHttpResponse getResponse() {
                    return new ResponseLoggingInterceptor(super.getResponse(), startTime);
                }
            };
            return chain.filter(exchangeDecorator)
                    .doOnSuccess(aVoid -> {
                        logResponse(startTime, exchangeDecorator.getResponse(), exchangeDecorator.getResponse().getStatusCode().value());
                    })
                    .doOnError(throwable -> {
                        logResponse(startTime, exchangeDecorator.getResponse(), 500);
                    });
        }
    }

    private void logResponse(long startTime, ServerHttpResponse response, int overriddenStatus) {
        final long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        LOGGER.info("Response({} ms): status={}, responseStatus:{}", duration, overriddenStatus, response.getHeaders());
    }

    private class RequestLoggingInterceptor extends ServerHttpRequestDecorator {

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestLoggingInterceptor.class);

        private boolean logHeaders;

        public RequestLoggingInterceptor(ServerHttpRequest delegate) {
            super(delegate);
        }

        @Override
        public Flux<DataBuffer> getBody() {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            return super.getBody().doOnNext(dataBuffer -> {
                try {
                    Channels.newChannel(baos).write(dataBuffer.asByteBuffer().asReadOnlyBuffer());
                    String body = IOUtils.toString(baos.toByteArray(), String.valueOf(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    if (logHeaders)
                        LOGGER.info("Request: method={}, uri={}, headers={}, payload={}", getDelegate().getMethod(),
                                getDelegate().getPath(), getDelegate().getHeaders(), body);
                    else
                        LOGGER.info("Request: method={}, uri={}, payload={}", getDelegate().getMethod(),
                                getDelegate().getPath(), body);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        baos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    private class ResponseLoggingInterceptor extends ServerHttpResponseDecorator {

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResponseLoggingInterceptor.class);
        private long startTime;

        public ResponseLoggingInterceptor(ServerHttpResponse delegate, long startTime) {
            super(delegate);
            this.startTime = startTime;
        }

        @Override
        public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
            Flux<DataBuffer> buffer = Flux.from(body);
            return super.writeWith(buffer.doOnNext(dataBuffer -> {
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                try {
                    Channels.newChannel(baos).write(dataBuffer.asByteBuffer().asReadOnlyBuffer());
                    String bodyRes = IOUtils.toString(baos.toByteArray(), String.valueOf(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    LOGGER.info("Response({} ms): status={}, payload={}", System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime,
                            getStatusCode().value(), bodyRes);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        baos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

The spring boot version - 2.6.7.
I used a simple controller for performance measure which returns a response as string and it do not have any other logic.

Comment: Do you use asynchronous logging?

Comment: @lkatiforis  - Thanks! No but switching to asyn did the trick

Comment: I think you are just facing thread/event loop starvation from blocking calls at `Channels.newChannel(baos).write(...)`